# reload page with onclick function that inculde in iframe page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages with names page1.html and page2.html. in page1 iframe page2

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="page2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

page2 includes some links with  tags. 
now I want when someone click any that links my page1 reload.
i use this in page2 for onclick funtion:

```
function refresh() {              
setTimeout(function () {
  location.reload()
    }, 100);
 }
```

but it reloads page2. I want to reload page1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use message.
in your `page2.html`

```
function refresh() {              
setTimeout(function () {
    parent.postMessage("reload","*");
    }, 100);
 }
```

in your `page1.html`

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
    var data = e[key];
      location.reload

},false);
```

[read this blog for detailed information](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe)